# How do I navigate the Outliner using the keyboard?

Tags: interface, shortcut, outliner

When I click on any item in the Outliner, and press Up or Down on the keyboard, I expect the selection to move, but nothing happens. Is there any way to enable keyboard navigation of the Outliner? Also, is there a shortcut to rename the currently selected object (like <kbd>F2</kbd> in Windows Explorer)?

What I want to do is rename many objects from Object.001, etc. to informative names quickly.

Comment: Double clicking on a name in the outliner will allow you to edit it. Every name needs to be unique.

Comment: or ctrl+leftmouse clicking.

Comment: Would like to know this too - and just to state this: apparently you cannot navigate nodes in Outliner with arrow up or down keyboard keys; when I press those keys in Outliner in Blender 2.79, it tells me "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction", meaning those keys there are reserved for navigating animation keyframes. I would have hoped there are other keys for navigating Outliner nodes, though...

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been added as of Blender 2.8

You can now rename with F2 from anywhere in the application, and navigate the Outliner with the keyboard (arrow keys).

Also in the Outliner, F2 works to rename the object under the mouse cursor. Ctrl + F2 will batch rename multiple selected objects.

However be advised: when in Outliner, although you can now navigate and select objects with the keyboard, F2 will always rename the object under the mouse cursor, not the object selected. (This is infuriating behaviour, and if anyone knows how to change it please let me know!)

Comment: The behavior of F2 (renaming the object under the mouse cursor instead of selected object) is fixed now (it seems).